# iOS image picker returning non-existent file path for video

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, uiimagepickercontroller

Consider the following method, annotated with its behavior.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    // Apparently valid URL, looks like
    // "file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../filename.mov"
    NSURL *videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]; 

    // Always evaluates to false; no videos are saved
    if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(videoURL.absoluteString) {        
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(videoURL.absoluteString, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
    }      
}
```

Why is this not working, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As their names suggest, the methods `UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum()` and `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum()` expect a *path*, not a URL. [Not the same thing.](http://www.skorks.com/2010/05/what-every-developer-should-know-about-urls/)

The string

`file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../filename.mov`

is a **URL**, composed of the **scheme**

`file://`

and **path**

`/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../filename.mov`

A function designed to accept a path will not work correctly when passed a complete URL.

To solve the problem, replace calls to `videoURL.absoluteString` with `videoURL.path`.